# Plugging in 1440p monitor from 1080p, first startup 1440p desktop locked at 1080p size until relog

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, icons, display-resolution

Here's the scenario:

1. Plug in 1440p monitor to 1080p laptop
2. Arrange desktop icons on 1440p desktop portion
3. turn of laptop, unplug and reboot
4. Desktop icons now on 1080p monitor, and jumbled, which is expected
5. turn off laptop, plug 1440p monitor back into laptop and reboot
6. Desktop icons are on 1440p side, but stuck in the jumbled 1080p "space" on the 1440p monitor, and cannot be dragged below 1080p in height (there is a no drag zone) or past 1920 (2560 - 1920 is grey zone).

To remedy this, I can relog / reboot and the 1440p monitor regains it's actual size and icon position.

Is there a reason for the icons / desktop being stuck when recently plugging in 1440p monitor from just 1080p? Any way to fix without a reboot of the laptop?

I understand `~/.config/xfce4/desktop` and the chatter command (which makes it so relog rearranges icons back to favourable position)

This report best encompasses the problem, except mine is specifically about the first connection of a non-1080p monitor to a 1080p monitor, which corrects itself after relog: [Bug link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfdesktop4/+bug/1190990)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pkill -HUP xfdesktop` seems to restart the desktop. Note that after testing, the desktop even if plugged in last session, still defaults to 1080p on startup, but after relog or pkill will reset.

For a permanent fix, add `pkill -HUP xfdesktop` to: Session and Startup > Application Autostart > +Add